# VBA Code for Excel to fetch Data from one sheet and conditionally transfer it to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, office365, vba7

I am trying to Write a VBA Code for the following problem

Here is the layout of existing sheet
1.Raw Data is Stored in "Raw Data" Sheet, Column A Contains Batch ID, Column B Contains Time Stamps Column C contains Values
2. Id is stored in A1 Cell of "Batch Number" Sheet
3. There are Time stamps in the "Batch Number" Sheet in A column starting from A2 cell with 1 sec increment.
4. The data is arranged in a chronological order, i.e. ascending order of time, in the "Raw Data" sheet the value of time stamp is in ascending order in Column B and In "Batch Number" Sheet the time stamps are arranged in a ascending order in Column A with 1 second increment in the subsequent row.
5. I need the program to print value in the column B of "Batch Number" Sheet such that if the Batch ID which is Cell A1 matches with the Batch ID which is Column A of "Raw Data" then we need to compare the time stamps in Column B of "Raw Data" sheet and Column A of "Batch Number" sheet, then we need to check if the time stamp is lower than the any time stamp within the previously matched rows of "Raw Data" Sheet then we will add "!!", if the time stamp within the previously matched rows of "Raw Data" sheet are equal or greater than the values of Column A and less than the value of next time stamp in the column B of "Raw Data" then print the corresponding value present in column C of "Raw Data" into the Column B of "Batch Data" sheet
Here is a VBA code in Excel that meets the specifications you provided:

I am using the following code :

```
Sub ExtractData()

Dim wsRawData As Worksheet
Dim wsBatchNumber As Worksheet
Dim lstRowRawData As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wsRawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
Set wsBatchNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch Number")

lstRowRawData = wsRawData.Cells(wsRawData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To wsBatchNumber.Cells(wsBatchNumber.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "A").Value < wsRawData.Cells(1, "B").Value Then
        wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "B").Value = "!!"
    Else
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To lstRowRawData - 1
            If wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "A").Value >= wsRawData.Cells(j, "B").Value And _
               wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "A").Value < wsRawData.Cells(j + 1, "B").Value Then
                wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "B").Value = wsRawData.Cells(j, "C").Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then wsBatchNumber.Cells(i, "B").Value = "**"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the "Raw Data" Sheet that I am using

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 12:31:04 | Running |
| ABC | 12:31:08 | Stop |
| ABC | 12:31:12 | Running |
| PQR | 12:33:01 | Idle |
| PQR | 12:33:15 | Running |

Here is the "Batch Number" Sheet I am using

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC |  |
| 12:31:02 |  |
| 12:31:03 |  |
| 12:31:04 |  |
| 12:31:05 |  |
| 12:31:06 |  |
| 12:31:07 |  |
| 12:31:08 |  |
| 12:31:09 |  |
| 12:31:10 |  |
| 12:31:11 |  |
| 12:31:12 |  |

I am expecting a following output in the "Batch Number" Sheet

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC |  |
| 12:31:02 | !! |
| 12:31:03 | !! |
| 12:31:04 | Running |
| 12:31:05 | Running |
| 12:31:06 | Running |
| 12:31:07 | Running |
| 12:31:08 | Stop |
| 12:31:09 | Stop |
| 12:31:10 | Stop |
| 12:31:11 | Stop |
| 12:31:12 | Running |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the remaining logic to your example code and made some minor style changes. I tend to use numbers for the rows and columns, since that works better with loops.

```
Sub ExtractData()

   Dim wsRawData As Worksheet
   Dim wsBatchNumber As Worksheet
   Dim lRawDataRows As Long
   Dim lBatchDataRows As Long
   Dim lRowBatch As Long
   Dim lRowRaw As Long
   Dim lFirstBatchRow As Long
   Dim lRowRawStart As Long
   Dim vTimeBatch As Variant
   Dim vTimeRaw As Variant

   Set wsRawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
   Set wsBatchNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch Number")

   lRawDataRows = wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   lBatchDataRows = wsBatchNumber.UsedRange.Rows.Count

   lFirstBatchRow = 0
   lRowRawStart = 1

   For lRowBatch = 2 To lBatchDataRows
       If lFirstBatchRow > 0 Then
           lRowRawStart = lFirstBatchRow
       End If
       For lRowRaw = lRowRawStart To lRawDataRows
           If wsBatchNumber.Cells(1, 1).Value = wsRawData.Cells(lRowRaw, 1).Value Then
               If lFirstBatchRow = 0 Then
                   lFirstBatchRow = lRowRaw
               End If
                
               vTimeBatch = wsBatchNumber.Cells(lRowBatch, 1).Value
               vTimeRaw = wsRawData.Cells(lRowRaw, 2).Value
            
               If vTimeBatch < vTimeRaw Then
                   If lRowRaw = lFirstBatchRow Then
                       wsBatchNumber.Cells(lRowBatch, 2).Value = "!!"
                   End If
                   Exit For
               ElseIf vTimeBatch = vTimeRaw Then
                   wsBatchNumber.Cells(lRowBatch, 2).Value = wsRawData.Cells(lRowRaw, 3).Value
                   Exit For
               ElseIf vTimeBatch > vTimeRaw Then
                   wsBatchNumber.Cells(lRowBatch, 2).Value = wsRawData.Cells(lRowRaw, 3).Value
               End If
           End If
       Next lRowRaw
   Next lRowBatch
End Sub
```